# My code is not comparing every row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is my code, I want to choose not exists in second table

```
select t.reg,
       t.dist,
       t.pkey,
       t.n_code,
       t.sum as s17,
       s.sum as s18
  from table1 t,
       (select *
          from table2 t
         where t.pkey is not null) s
 where t.pkey= s.pkey
   and t.reg= s.reg
   and t.dist= s.dist
   and t.a = 99
   and s.a != 99
   and t.n_code= 66
   and t.n_code = s.n_code
   and t.sum > 0
   and t.sum not in s.sum  --not in is not working i think
   and t.reg= 33
   and t.dist= 1
```

t.sum is not being compared in every row in second table, the value from first table exists in second table but in another row.

code not searching other rows as well
**PL/SQL**

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

`Not in` doesn't work like this. Syntax of `Not in` is `t.sum Not in (10,20)`, you can also use subquery instead of static values.

But here `Not In` doesn't required. You can replace the following

```
and t.sum not in s.sum
```

with

```
and t.sum <> s.sum
```

Comment: i have done this, but didn't work.
the value from table one exists in table2 but in another row.
Code compares only first row

Comment: Because other conditions are also there so only first row is satisfying all the conditions. And if required Then you can use subquery with not in : ‘t.sum not in (select sum from table2)’

Comment: ‘t.sum not in (select sum from table2)’  I have done this also. Number of rows is more, may be because of this code is not working

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help? Somewhat *prettier* code with explicit joins and conditions moved to `where` clause.

```
select t.reg,
       t.dist,
       t.pkey,
       t.n_code,
       t.sum as s17,
       s.sum as s18
  from table1 t join table2 s
    on  t.pkey= s.pkey
    and t.reg= s.reg
    and t.dist= s.dist
    and t.n_code = s.n_code
    and t.sum <> s.sum        --> this
  where t.pkey is not null
    and t.a = 99
    and s.a != 99
    and t.n_code= 66
    and t.sum > 0
    and t.reg= 33
    and t.dist= 1
```

Comment: Looks like it *should*. Could you, please, provide sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `not exists`, but faster is to add conditional `count()` checking if sums are the same (in whole window). If this count<>0 remove row from output.

```
select reg, dist, pkey, n_code, s17, s18 
  from (
    select t.reg, t.dist, t.pkey, t.n_code, t.sum as s17, s.sum as s18, 
           count(case when t.sum = s.sum then 1 end) 
             over (partition by t.pkey, t.reg, t.dist, t.n_code) cnt_same
      from table1 t
      join (select * from table2 t where t.pkey is not null) s
        on t.pkey = s.pkey and t.reg = s.reg and t.dist = s.dist and t.n_code = s.n_code
       where t.a = 99 and s.a != 99 and t.n_code= 66 
         and t.sum > 0 and t.reg= 33 and t.dist = 1)
  where cnt_same = 0
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee5b48c06a448670db4f6328f09ef174)</sup>**

This part is important:

```
over (partition by t.pkey, t.reg, t.dist, t.n_code)
```

It determines in which range we are checking sums. If you want to scan whole table use:

```
over ()
```

if you want only same pkey use

```
over (partition by t.pkey)
```

Comment: thank you for help...
But your code is also didn't work...
Any other suggestions